# How to read a RepeatedField (or at least its Count) using Google.Protobuf.Reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I am writing tests for a C# application supporting several Protobuf definitions of the same objects... which are unfortunately not very compatible to each other.

So I have written the following utility methods using [Google.Protobuf.Reflection](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/namespace/google/protobuf/reflection):

```
namespace ProtobufUtils
{
    using Google.Protobuf;
    using Google.Protobuf.Collections;
    using Google.Protobuf.Reflection;
    ...

    public static uint ReadUint(this IMessage msg, string fieldName)
    {
        FieldDescriptor field = msg.Descriptor.FindFieldByName(fieldName);
        return (uint)field.Accessor.GetValue(msg);
    }

    public static string ReadString(this IMessage msg, string fieldName)
    {
        FieldDescriptor field = msg.Descriptor.FindFieldByName(fieldName);
        return (string)field.Accessor.GetValue(msg);
    }
```

Using the above methods I am able to read out some common fields from `IMessage` objects in my tests:

```
    [DataTestMethod]
    [DynamicData(nameof(GetAllVersionsToTest), typeof(BaseUnitTest), DynamicDataSourceType.Method)]
    public async Task GetConfigurationShouldContainSessionToken(uint version)
    {
        IMessage cfgReq = ProtobufUtils.GenerateConfigRequest(version);

        uint reqVersion = ProtobufUtils.ReadUint(cfgReq, "version");
        string reqId = ProtobufUtils.ReadString(cfgReq, "id");
        string reqEtag = ProtobufUtils.ReadString(cfgReq, "etag");
```

My question is:

Sometimes I also need to assert, that a `RepeatedField` has no elements.

How to do it please, by using reflection?

For example, in the .proto file I have:

```
message ConfigurationResponse {
    uint32 version = 1;
    string id= 2;
    string etag = 3;
    repeated ContainerConfiguration configuration = 4;
    reserved 5, 6;
}
```

How can I read out the `ContainerConfiguration` field using reflection and verify, that it is empty?

(and I do have to use reflection, because there are 4 not very compatible versions of `ContainerConfiguration` to be supported by our application).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Introduction

Let's consider the following versions as the current versions:

- .NET SDK `6.0.302` (Commit: `c857713418`).

  - Target Framework: .NET `6.0`.
- Protocol Buffer Compiler (`protoc`): `3.12.4`.
- `Google.Protobuf` NuGet package: `3.21.4`.

## Possible solution

Actually, you could use the exact type:

```cs
(RepeatedField<T>)field.Accessor.GetValue(msg);
```

Let's keep in mind your note:

> (and I do have to use reflection, because there are 4 not very compatible versions of `ContainerConfiguration` to be supported by our application).

Let's refer to the documentation: [Google.Protobuf.Collections.RepeatedField Class Reference  |  Protocol Buffers  |  Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/class/google/protobuf/collections/repeated-field-t-):

> #### Inheritance
>
> Inherits from: IList< T >, IList, [Google.Protobuf.IDeepCloneable< T >](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/interface/google/protobuf/i-deep-cloneable-t-), IEquatable< RepeatedField< T >>
>
> <…>
>
> Last updated 2016-09-27 UTC.

To check the number of elements in the list without taking into account the exact type of the elements, it would be enough to use non-generic `IList` interface:

```cs
(IList)field.Accessor.GetValue(msg);
```

### Draft example program

#### `.proto` file

```
syntax = "proto3";

message ConfigurationResponse {
    uint32 version = 1;
    string id = 2;
    string etag = 3;
    repeated ContainerConfiguration configuration = 4;
    reserved 5, 6;
}

message ContainerConfiguration {
    string id = 1;
}
```

Generate the C# code by using `protoc`.

#### `MessageFactory` class

```cs
using Google.Protobuf;

internal sealed class MessageFactory
{
    public static IMessage Create()
    {
        var configurationResponse = new ConfigurationResponse
            {
                Version = 1,
                Id = "First ID",
                Etag = "The tag"
            };
        
        configurationResponse.Configuration.Add(new[]
            {
                new ContainerConfiguration
                    {
                        Id = "1",
                    },
                new ContainerConfiguration
                    {
                        Id = "2"
                    }
            }
        );
        
        return configurationResponse;
    }
}
```

#### `ProtobufUtils` class

```cs
using System.Collections;
using Google.Protobuf;
using Google.Protobuf.Reflection;

internal static class ProtobufUtils
{
    public static IList ReadRepeated(this IMessage msg, string fieldName)
    {
        FieldDescriptor field = msg.Descriptor.FindFieldByName(fieldName);
        return (IList)field.Accessor.GetValue(msg);
    }
}
```

#### `Program` class

```cs
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var message = MessageFactory.Create();
        
        var configurationList = message.ReadRepeated("configuration");
        
        Console.WriteLine("Configuration list count: {0}", configurationList.Count);
    }
}
```

#### Program output

```
Configuration list count: 2
```